# Providing unique results for multiple clients simultaneously

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a single table with a few million rows, hundres of clients are accessing this table simultaneously, each one needs to get 20 unique rows, which then needs to be placed last in line.

My setup is:

Table structure:

```
id | last_access | reserved_id | [Data columns]
id + last_access is indexed
```

For selecting 20 unique rows I use the following:

```
UPDATE "table" SET "reserved" = 'client-id_timestamp' WHERE "reserved" = ''ORDER BY "last_access" ASC LIMIT 20
```

This update query is quite bad performance wise, which is why I ask:

Is there a better solution for my specific requirements? Another table structure perhaps?

Comment: Use backtics around column names, not quotes -- quotes are for strings.

Comment: It was just an example, but noted anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Is last_access a date column? Try expressing it with an integer value (ie. seconds since 1970-01-01), it might be faster to sort.

Second performance issue might come from the need to reindex the table after you change the "reserved" field. It is possible that the performance might improve if you remove the index from that column. Though the search will take longer, the more expensive reindex is thrown out of the equation.

If you are using MySQL 5.6.3 or newer, you can execute [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) with your query to find out what part of it takes the longest.

Comment: Actually removing the index on the column reserved, fixed some performance issues, so thanks for this!
I still think there should be a better solution, on how to handle this scenario?
Performance is getting worse as the number of rows increase..

Comment: Maybe you could deswcribe what are you trying to do in more details. Why do you have to order by last access? Why limit 20? Maybe it would help to put data columns in a separate table and keep this table to a minimum.
You could also keep a much shorter table (100k rows). When you access an object insert/update its row into this "cache" table and have a pruning mechanism that deletes old entries at some time interval.

Comment: Don't reindex.  Although it is costly to update the index because you are changing a value in the index, it would be a lot more costly to reindex the entire table.

Comment: Optimal index:  `INDEX(reserved, last_access)`.  (`EXPLAIN` won't tell you this.)